# Holding B1 -B2 Visa and already applied F1

Tags: f1-visas

My son university is in Texas and our family holding B1/B2 visa now my son will apply for F1 visa.

Our issue is that we have already planned Bahamas cruise from Miami on 16th August and my son college is in Texas will open by 21st August.

Now the real issue is if my son enters US with F-1 visa the I-20 form need to be stamped prior to exit USA and which may not possible. seeking possible suggestion.

Comment: You should contact the university for advice. I-20 travel endorsement can usually be done immediately (during specific international student office hours) or within one day.

Answer (score 3):

Your first step should be to ask the university's advice.  The safest plan is to enter the US as F-1 up to 30 days before the I-20 start date, go to the university first and get the travel signature, and then travel to the Bahamas, returning to the university in time for classes.

While you could risk entering as F-1 both times without getting a travel signature yet, this approach runs the risk of a major hassle.  For example, you might be issued an I-515A.

A more clever approach would be to try to enter as B-2 the first time and then F-1 when you reenter from the Bahamas. The main risk of this approach would merely be if the officer disagreed with or misunderstood your intention, in which case you might be admitted in the wrong status.

In any event, your first step should be to ask the university's advice.  They ought to help you with this kind of situation.  It would be unusual for a university to say they can't issue a travel signature because they won't be open yet.  If they really did say that, please edit your question to explain what they said.